# Python: l2-Penalty for logistic regression model from statsmodels?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Is there a way to put an l2-Penalty for the logistic regression model in statsmodel through a parameter or something else? I just found the l1-Penalty in the docs but nothing for the l2-Penalty.

Comment: Can you provide a link or address to the documentation you've found?

Comment: I'm referring to this model from statsmodels: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.html

To fit the model with regularization, you probably can use this method:http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.fit_regularized.html#statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.fit_regularized

For the parameter method, I just found the options ` ‘l1’ or ‘l1_cvxopt_cp’`, that both are probably the options I'm searching for

Comment: Wow!  That documentation is not clear.  I'm sorry, I can't make any definitive sense of it.  I've written solvers that handle l2.  It's generally easier to solve with an l2 penalty as the cost functions are everywhere differentiable thus the gradient exists.  I have to assume it's there somewhere.  Wish I could help more.

Comment: Sorry, in my first comment I meant of course that both options are NOT the ones I'm looking for.

I'm not that much into the details of realizing a penalty in the logistic regression model therefore I'm just looking for an easy option to choose between the option to turn the l2-penalty on and off like in the scikit package. Unfortunately in this package I don't have such a nice summary of the logistic regression with all the p values and stuff

Answer (score 3):

The models in statsmodels.discrete like Logit, Poisson and MNLogit have currently only L1 penalization. However, elastic net for GLM and a few other models has recently been merged into statsmodels master.

GLM with family binomial with a binary response is the same model as discrete.Logit although the implementation differs. See my answer for L2 penalization in [Is ridge binomial regression available in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441450/is-ridge-binomial-regression-available-in-python/37499381#37499381)

What has not yet been merged into statsmodels is L2 penalization with a structured penalization matrix as it is for example used as roughness penality in generalized additive models, GAM, and spline fitting.

Answer (score 3):

If you look closely at the Documentation for [`statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit_regularized`](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit_regularized.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit_regularized) you'll see that the current version of statsmodels allows for Elastic Net regularization which is basically just a convex combination of the L1- and L2-penalties (though more robust implementations employ some post-processing to diminish undesired behaviors of the naive implementations, see "Elastic Net" on Wikipedia for details):

[image: ElasticNet][2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization)

If you take a look at the parameters for `fit_regularized` in the documentation:

`OLS.fit_regularized(method='elastic_net', alpha=0.0, L1_wt=1.0, start_params=None, profile_scale=False, refit=False, **kwargs)`

you'll realize that `L1_wt` is just lambda_1 in the first equation. So to get the L2-Penalty you're looking for, you just pass `L1_wt=0` as an argument when you call the function. As an example:

```
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit_regularized(method='elastic_net', alpha=1.0, L1_wt=0.0)
print(results.summary())
```

should give you  an L2 Penalized Regression predicting target `y` from input `X`.

Three final comments:

1. statsmodels currently only implements `elastic_net` as an option to the `method` argument. So that gives you L1 and L2 and any linear combination of them but nothing else (for OLS at least);
2. L1 Penalized Regression = LASSO (least absolute shrinkage and selection operator);
3. L2 Penalized Regression = Ridge Regression, the Tikhonov–Miller method, the Phillips–Twomey method, the constrained linear inversion method, and the method of linear regularization.

Comment: Cool, but this is OLS, not logistic regression.

Comment: For regularized logistic regression: m = statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM(y, X, family=families.Binomial(link=links.Logit)) ; m.fit_regularized(...)?

Comment: So... in your example, does L2 = alpha when L1_wt=0? (alpha = L1+L2 ... does this work if we want to set L1=0, L2=10)?

Comment: When I try `logistic_regression_model = sm.GLM(
    y,
    X,
    link=sm.genmod.families.links.logit)
results = logistic_regression_model.fit_regularized(alpha=1.)
results.summary()`, I get an error on `results.summary()` that summary is not implemented. Why does my `fit_regularized()` not return a summary?